# return values from xml in python

Tags: python, xml

What would be a good way of returning the known Min and Max values from the xml below using python's `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`

I'm struggling to find a clean way of getting the Max and Min values, so I'm open to any suggestions. I'm not in control of the XML creation.

Here is a snippet of my xml.

```
<options>
    <option>
        <name v="clamp"/>
        <value v="0"/>
    </option>
    <option>
        <name v="default"/>
        <value v="10"/>
    </option>
    <option>
        <name v="max"/>
        <value v="10"/>
    </option>
    <option>
        <name v="min"/>
        <value v="0"/>
    </option>
    <option>
        <name v="step"/>
        <value v="1"/>
    </option>
</options>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you want to check attribute of element `name` if it is equal to `min` or `max`. If so, you can get the value from `value` element by access though attribute and get value from key `v`.

Here is the snippet to find `min` and `max` value from the given string (named as `text`) using `lxml` library.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring(text) # or etree.parse if you want to parse XML file instead

for e in tree.xpath('//option'):
    if e.find('name').attrib.get('v') == 'min':
        min_val = e.find('value').attrib.get('v')
    if e.find('name').attrib.get('v') == 'max':
        max_val = e.find('value').attrib.get('v')

print(min_val, max_val) # ('0', '10')
```

**note** that you might have to write if/else statement if the attribute does not exist. In that case, it can return `None` which gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you could use `xml.etree.ElementTree.XMLParser` if your xml is already read as string:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import XMLParser

class Parser:                     # The target object of the parser

  min = 0
  max = 0
  store_max = False
  store_min = False

  def start(self, tag, attrib):   # Called for each opening tag.

    if self.store_max:
      self.max = attrib.get('v')
      self.store_max = False

    if self.store_min:
      self.min = attrib.get('v')
      self.store_min = False

    if attrib.get('v') == 'max':
      self.store_max = True
    if attrib.get('v') == 'min':
      self.store_min = True

  def end(self, tag):             # Called for each closing tag.
    pass                          # We do not need to do anything when tag is closing.

  def data(self, data):
    pass                          # We do not need to do anything with data.

  def close(self):    # Called when all data has been parsed.
    return self.min, self.max


xml = """<options>
    <option>
        <name v="clamp"/>
        <value v="0"/>
    </option>
    <option>
        <name v="default"/>
        <value v="10"/>
    </option>
    <option>
        <name v="max"/>
        <value v="10"/>
    </option>
    <option>
        <name v="min"/>
        <value v="0"/>
    </option>
    <option>
        <name v="step"/>
        <value v="1"/>
    </option>
</options>"""

target = Parser()
parser = XMLParser(target=target)
parser.feed(xml)
print(parser.close())
```